# Referencing first child and getting object reference error

Tags: c#

I have two different XML responses that can be returned. They look like this:

1) Gets returned if no user.

```
<ArrayUser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

2: Gets returned if user found.

```
<ArrayUser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <User>
    <Name></Name>
    <ID></ID>
  </User>
```

Here is my current code:

```
        if (userLookupResponse.DocumentElement.FirstChild.Name.Equals("User")) 
        {
            XmlNamespaceManager nsm = addXmlNamespaces(userLookupResponse);
            userLookupResponse.LoadXml(userLookupResponse.SelectSingleNode("//SSO:User", nsm).OuterXml);
            return userLookupResponse;
        }
```

My issue is that if a user isn't returned it errors on the `if` statement with an object reference not set to instance of an object error. How can I go inside the if statement only if number 2 is returned with user information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if (userLookupResponse.DocumentElement.FirstChild.Name.Equals("User"))

I am guessing that FirstChild will be null since there is no child.

Why not change your test abit to see:

> if (userLookupResponse.DocumentElement.FirstChild != null)

Comment: Yes, that worked. I was trying just `userLookupResponse != null`. Thanks for helping.